# kinect development with windows c# or c++?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, kinect

I'm totally new to windows development.I'm coming from Objective-c but now i wanna start to develop for the solution Kinect-Windows. I have to choose between C++ and C# , one of this languages is more appropriate to kinect development? I'm inclined to C++ but i don't know if C# will made all things easier, maybe more support for kinect?

EDIT
Another question, i need to buy the Kinect window sensor ? Or to develop i can use a standard xbox Kinect sensor?

Comment: This is primarily an opinion based question and therefor not [germane](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the official Kinect SDK, it [supports C++, C# and VB](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindowsdev/Downloads.aspx). Use the language which best suites your needs.

To answer your second question, you can use the Kinect for Windows sensor or the Kinect for Xbox 360 sensor. The choice is yours.

However, there are some notable differences. This [blog post](http://www.kinectingforwindows.com/2012/09/07/what-is-the-difference-between-kinect-for-windows-kinect-for-xbox360/) does a good job of explaining them. Below are the main features that the Windows sensors offers over the Xbox sensor, taken from the blog encase the link breaks in the future.

> **Near mode:** Enables the camera to see objects as close as 40 centimeters
>   in front of the device without losing accuracy or precision, with
>   graceful degradation out to 3 meters.
>
> **Seated or “10 joint” mode:** Skeletal tracking which provides the
>   capability to track the head, neck and arms of either a seated or
>   standing user.
>
> **USB cable:** Ensures reliability across a broad range of computers and
>   improves coexistence with other USB peripherals.
>
> **Extended camera settings:** Provides extra settings such as brightness,
>   exposure, etc. so you can tune it even more.
>
> **Kinect Fusion:** Maps the environnement to 3D on the fly or lets you use
>   object replacement.
>
> **Handgrip:** Hand detection enables you to implement gestures like
>   pinch-to-zoom, grab, etc. to improve your apps and build whole new
>   kind of applications.
>
> **Licensing:** When you want to go public with you’re application you’ll need to use a Kinect for Windows. Kinect for Xbox 360 isn’t legal.

Comment: Please note that link is slightly outdated, Seated/Fusion/HandGrip is available to XBox sensor as well now.